Java AWT SystemTray Problem with icons and OpenJDK Platform binary
Java 22 JDK
In the main, I call the method  SystemNotificationUtil.notification() with TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE
@Slf4j
public class SystemNotificationUtil {

    private static SystemTray tray;
    private static Image image;
    private static TrayIcon trayIcon;

    static {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("favicon.ico");
            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray");

            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
            trayIcon.setToolTip("System tray demo");

            try {
                tray.add(trayIcon);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                log.error("SystemNotificationUtil", e);
            }

        } else log.info("SystemNotificationUtil: System tray not supported");
    }

    public static void notification(String title, String message, TrayIcon.MessageType messageType) {
        trayIcon.displayMessage(title, message, messageType);
    }



Problems:

The alert comes from the OpenJDK binary Platform, and not from the application being launched

The application icon is not displayed in the application window

There is an empty space in the tray instead of the icon


I found a solution in which the packed java.exe with the help of some utility, they prescribe a different value instead of OpenJDK binary Platform, but I would not like to engage in such perversions, and it will not fix the other 2 problems.
If it is impossible to get rid of this somehow, maybe you can recommend some other lib?
For context, about the executable file: using launch4j-maven-plugin, I pack my jar into exe, dependencies and JDK are simply transferred to the target
EDIT: Maybe someone know how to use this?
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.mobanisto</groupId>
    <artifactId>toast4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>

lib repo
From a brief readme, I realized that this is a dependency for accessing the "new" Windows API for displaying notifications, but I still couldn't figure out how to use it, maybe it could solve my problems
